# I'm struggling getting back id from postgresql in Play

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, anorm

I'm struggling inserting a record into a postgresql:

```
val res = DB.withConnection {
        implicit con =>
          SQL(
            """INSERT INTO
              my_table(id, user_id, file_name, added_at)
              VALUES(DEFAULT, {userId}, {fileName}, {currentTime})
              RETURNING id
            """)
            .on("userId" -> 1, "fileName" -> "fileName1", "currentTime" -> new java.sql.Timestamp(DateTime.now.getMillis))
            .executeInsert()
      }

Ok(toJson(JsObject(Seq("res" -> JsString(res.toString)))))
```

It does insert a value (which I can see via pdAdmin) but it returns an error eventually `ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING"`.

If I remove `RETURNING id` then the error becomes `TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert requestBody4050249427671619471asTemporaryFile                                                                                                                                                                                                                  :class java.lang.String to Long for column ColumnName(my_table.file_name,Some(file_name)))]]`

When I cut off `id` and `DEFAULT` the error remains the same.

`my_table` defined is

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  file_name character(255),
  user_id integer,
  added_at timestamp without time zone,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT my_table_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT scan_fk FOREIGN .....
)
```

Why is that? What it has to do with `file_name` anyway?

Comment: Usually if you use `RETURNING` you need to issue it more like a `SELECT` query; e.g. in regular Java you'd use `execute` not `executeUpdate`, so it fetched a ResultSet. I suspect what's happening here is that PgJDBC or Play is adding its own `RETURNING` clause for you implicitly. Check the *server error log* for details - are there two `RETURNING` clauses in your query?

Comment: where is "server error log"?

Comment: The PostgreSQL server produces a log. Google will tell you about it. By default whenever any client runs a statement that causes an error the server logs the error message. Look in this error log and you will see the error message and the statement that caused the error, which can be very informative.

Comment: Are you sure the `file_name` column type should REALLY be the `character(255)`? I assume anorm has some difficulties on inserting into a character column. Did you try changing the type to a `varchar(255)`?

Comment: @serejja, thanks, you're right. In postgres, however, it is character varying(255), is not it?

Comment: Both variants work - `character varying(255)` and `varchar(255)`

Answer (score 1):

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  file_name character(255),
  user_id integer,
  added_at timestamp without time zone,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT my_table_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You can insert a record and retrieve its id like this:

```
package dao

import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
import play.api.db.DB
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.Play.current

object MyDAO {

  def insert(fileName: String, userId: Int): Int = {
    val sql = SQL(
      """
        insert into my_table(file_name, user_id, added_at)
        values ({fileName}, {userId}, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        returning id
      """)
      .on(
        "fileName" -> fileName,
        "userId" -> userId)
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      val id = sql.as(scalar[Int].single)
      Logger.info(s"Inserted '$fileName' with id '$id'.")
      id
    }
  }

}
```

And test it like this:

```
import org.junit.runner._
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import dao.MyDAO

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MyDAOSpec extends Specification {
  "MyDAO" should {
    "insert a record and return its id" in new WithApplication {
      val id = MyDAO.insert("file1", 101)
      id must be_>=(0)
    }
  }
}
```

See [Anorm, simple SQL data access](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaAnorm) for more examples of how to retrieve data from result sets.

Comment: The relation is that this answer shows you a way to insert a record returning the id without causing the errors you described. The first error was caused by using executeInsert for returning data. The second, for trying to get a result out a statement that doesn't return a result set.

Comment: I'm asking about the solution of my problem, not an example how to do the same thing.

Comment: Alex, I provided you with a detailed, correct solution. What do you think is missing?

Comment: Since you're not willing to cooperate and keep a civil tone, I can't help you.

Comment: But you were implying you already had helped me, weren't you?